# Как вывести имена и типы переменных в файле?

Tags: java

Подскажите идею!

К примеру, есть файл *.java. Требуется: вывести имена всех переменных в файле и их типы. Тип переменной может быть любой, не только примитивные, при этом игнорируя комментарии.

Код от комментариев я отделил. Может, кто сталкивался с такой задачей или есть мысли, как это сделать? Может есть какая-нибудь литература по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 2):

1. Взять генератор парсеров (анализаторов синтаксиса) - имя им легион. На c - yacc/bison, java - JavaCC и др. Найти/написать описание java на них. Навесить нужную обработку.
2. Сделать разбор с помощью регулярных выражение. Образец, например, файл java-синтаксиса в vim (там правда синтаксис регэкспов особый). Добавить нужную обработку (ведение таблиц). Правда вероятность ошибки при таком разборе выше (некоторые трюки в исходниках регэкспами ловить тяжело)
3. Что-нибудь ещё...

Comment: С javacc идёт в комплекте описание Java5. Там есть небольшой бажец в описании импортов, но в целом работает. Так что задача решается через javacc на раз-два.

Comment: В качестве "что-нибудь ещё" можно рассмотреть Java Compiler API и Compiler Tree API.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно не о том вопрос, но на всякий случай:
[javap ClassName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html)